# Absolute Continuity, Lipschitz

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, continuity

I'm studying for a qualifying exam and can't seem to solve this problem.  Any suggestions would be appreciated!

> Let $f:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb R$ be absolutely continuous.  Show, for each $\epsilon>0$, that there is a uniformly Lipschitz function(global) $g:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb R$ such that $|f(x)-g(x)|<\epsilon$ for all $x\in [a,b]$.

Comment: By $\,\Re\,,\,Re\,$ , did you mean $\,\Bbb R\,$ = the real numbers?

Comment: @DonAntonio I would be very surprised if he didn't.

Comment: What do you mean by *uniformly* Lipschitz?  If it means something similar to what I call Lipschitz, then, hint: the Weierstrass approximation theorem.  (And if so, then *absolutely* continuous is a red herring).

Comment: So would I, @PeterTamaroff

Comment: Sorry I did mean the real numbers.  Yes Lipschitz and uniformly Lipschitz are the same for this instructor apparently:p

Comment: Okay so we didn't cover that theorem but I see that the result follows at once.  However why does $f$ need to be absolutely continuous.  The version of the theorem I read said that f only needs to be continuous?

Comment: Do I need to add @NateEldredge to my post for it to flag you?

Comment: @Dave: Indeed, that's what I meant by "red herring".  This would work fine for continuous functions.  (As a wild guess: is it possible you've miscopied the question, and it's instead asking that $|f'(x) - g'(x)| < \epsilon$?)

Comment: @NateEldredge Yes that's very odd.  I double checked and I copied the question correctly.  Perhaps since we didn't cover that theorem there is a different way so solve it.

Comment: The current title is very uninformative. Guys, can you come up with something with something more informative; better titles help future better search this website & benefit from the answers (I don't have a suggestion though).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on my comment:

One approach is just to invoke the Weierstrass approximation theorem.  This works even if $f$ is merely continuous, and it gives a $g$ which is a polynomial, which is drastically stronger than just being Lipschitz or even $C^\infty$.

You could also give a more direct proof.  An absolutely continuous function has a derivative which is $L^1$; a Lipschitz function has a derivative which is bounded.  You can approximate $L^1$ functions by bounded functions.  Now, to get from the derivative back to the function, what could you do...?

Indeed, integrate.  So find a bounded measurable function $h$ which is close to $f'$ in $L^1$ norm.  What can you say about the difference between the integrals (from $a$ to $x$) of $f'$ and $h$?

So we can get $\int_a^x f'(t) dt - \int_a^x h(t)dt$ to be small, right?  Or in other words, we can get $f(x) - f(a) - \int_a^x h(t)dt$ to be small.  So what if we set $g(x) = f(a) + \int_a^x h(t)dt$?

Comment: Integrate?  Your second approach is what I tried to figure out before but I can't seem to get anywhere.

Comment: That's what I tried doing and I get that $f(x)-h(x) = \int_{a}^{x}f'(t) + f(a) - \int_{a}^{x}h'(t) - h(a)$.  But I don't quite see how or why $f(a)$ and $h(a)$ are related?

Comment: @Dave: Careful, I am choosing $h$ to be close to $f'$, not to $f$.  My $h$ is merely bounded measurable and I don't expect it to be differentiable at all.  We want to be comparing $f$ with $\int_a^x h(t)dt$.  See edit.

Comment: So do I want something like $h(x)=\chi_{E_M}f'(x)$ where $E_{M}={x:|f'(x)\leq M|}$ is the set such that $f'(x)$ is bounded?  How do I know that $h(x)$ is close enough?

Comment: @Dave: For any $\delta > 0$, you can find $M$ so large that the corresponding $h$ has $\int |f'(x) - h(x)| < \delta$.  Now see what kind of bound on $|f-g|$ you get in terms of $\delta$.

Comment: I see so now I have the following $|f(x)-g(x)|=|f(x)-f(a) + \int_{a}^{x}h(t)dt|=\int_{a}^{x}|f'(t)-h(t)|dt<\epsilon$.  But since $h(x)=\chi_{E_m}f$ I have that $f'$ is bounded on $E_M$ and $f$ is absolutely continuous so $h(x)$ is Lipschitz.

Answer (score 0):

Theorem: Let M be a metric space. Then any continuous function f:M→R can be uniformly approximated by a locally Lipschitz functions. See [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/43625/approximation-by-locally-lipschitz-functions).

Remember that if a function is absolutely continuous on $[a,b]$ then it is continuous on $[a,b]$. The converse is not true.

Comment: I asked the professor today about this question and he said that g should be uniform Lipschitz(global) not just local